# NetSuite - Sublist field as link

Tags: netsuite

I have two custom records. They share parent-child record relationship. Child record is shown as sublist view. On Child record, there is a field called Delivery Order. It is a list/record field, But not having hyperlink to open that record. This field is list of a custom record of same name.

There is also a field called Sales Order#, it is a list/record field of Transaction. But it is shown as link which is right.
[image: Custom Record]
I want to have hyperlink for Delivery Order. I know that if I use a custom view, I can give a formula(text) field to show that field as a hyperlink, But I want to go with Default View only. I think because of Delivery Order is a custom record, they are not giving hyperlink.